# Send email to multiple recipients using individual SMTP transactions with MailKit

Tags: c#, email, office365, mailkit

In my environment we send email programatically using MailKit via Office 365 SMTP. I have recently become aware of the fact that if I send an email with multiple recipients and one of those addresses no longer exists in our organization the O365 server will reject the entire email (not sending it to the remaining recipients) if a single recipient is invalid. The error generated is

```
5.4.1 Recipient address rejected: Access denied.
```

When I send emails I prefer to show all recipients on the email so that everyone knows who is involved and can reply to the group. All recipients are within my organization so they already have each others email addresses.

Based on the way SMTP works (with separate RCPT and headers) it seems that I should be able to send an email with everyone in the headers, but use individual transactions with the SMTP server so I can catch the exception generated for each address.

Is this possible to do with MailKit?

Comment: Doesn't the failed email address show up in your inbox?  SMTP only has a TO ADDRESS where you place all recipients.

Comment: The emails are all auto generated so they come from a DoNotReply@example.com type address that I don't have access to.


It was my understanding that when you send via SMTP, you first specify the actual recipients that the email is delivered to by the RCPT TO command, and then you also place those addresses in the headers. I thought that is how the BCC option worked if you place someone in the RCPT to without displaying them in the header.

Comment: RCPT TO is just where a Receipt goes to after person responds.  BCC is blind and the person who receives email doesn't see everybody else who get the email.

Comment: @jdweng and so others are not mislead by your "after person responds" comment,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into the Send() and SendAsync() methods that take MailboxAddress arguments:

http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/M_MailKit_MailTransport_Send_2.htm

This allows you to control who, exactly, to send the message to rather than having MailKit's SmtpClient decide who to send the message to by collecting addresses from the To, Cc and Bcc headers.

Comment: This is precisely the answer I was looking for. By passing in the to and from parameters separately in the send function, it uses those for the MAIL FROM and RCPT TO commands and then uses the parameters in the mail message itself for the headers. This means I can send the emails in a foreach loop (catching any exception) while the recipients can still see everyone else who received the email.

Comment: Another note for anyone looking for a similar solution, the documentation for the Send function points out: "If either the Resent-Sender or Resent-From addresses are present, the recipients are collected from the Resent-To, Resent-Cc, and Resent-Bcc headers, otherwise the To, Cc, and Bcc headers are used."